# How to calculate corrected Gas Volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

We are working on a project called 'Electronic Gas Volume Corrector'. The device reads pressure and temperature from sensors mounted on a gas pipe and gas volume from a gas meter. These are the flowing condition parameters : $p_f$, $T_f$ and $V_f$. A computer code then uses the following equation to calculate gas volume in "base" conditions :

$V_b = V_f \times P_f/P_b \times Z_b/Z_f \times T_b/T_f$

This equation tells us how gas volume would be if it was measured in billing conditions for the same number of moles n as in the flowing conditions.

These are the billing conditions values: $T_b = \pu{15°C}, P_b = \pu{1 atm}, Z_b =0.978$. The gas in question is *propane*. I found Zb in [this](https://encyclopedia.airliquide.com/propane#properties) website.

The only parameter left to determine is $Z_f$, and we do not know how to calculate it, especially since it depends on sensors readings of flowing conditions $P_f$ and $T_f$. I tried using $PV=nZRT$ but the number of moles is always unknown since it depends on gas consumption, and $V/n$ which is the molar volume and also depends on $T$ and $p$ according to my research, and we do not know how to calculate it.

What are we missing ? Is there any other equation that helps in calculating $Z_f$ ?

Comment: There should be tables of empirical formulas to get compressibility factor of the real gas  Z as function of p and T.

Comment: What is the meaning of the indexes $b$ and $f$ ?

Comment: @Poutnik we found some old documents about Volume correction but they use graphs (Z(P) for a few values of T ) instead of equations. If you can share links/titles it will be much appreciated

Comment: @Maurice b is for billing conditions and f for flowing (real) conditions
Two consumers might get different bills even if they consume the same energy because of different T and P, that's why we need to convert flowing Volume to a base Volume calculated in the billing conditions

Comment: One possible way is calculating V or Z from van der Waals' state equation for real gases.

Comment: See Smith and Van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics for graphs of z as a function of $T/T_c$, $P/P_c$, and ascentric factor $\omega$, where $T_c$ and $P_c$ are the critical temperature and pressure and $\omega$ is a tabulated (constant) physical property characteristic of the specific gas under consideration.

Comment: Poutnik's suggestion, about using van der Waals equation, is the best, and the simplest, as it needs only two correcting factors.

Comment: I found this equation :$ Z = \frac{V_m}{V_m-b} - \frac{a}{V_m R T} $ but the problem the molar volume figures in it. Is it always constant and equals 22.4 l/mol ?

Comment: I found something interesting in this website (https://www.e-education.psu.edu/png301/node/840#:~:text=Gas%20Super%2DCompressibility%20Factor%2C%20Z,pressure%20and%20high%20temperature%20conditions.) Equation 3.66 seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I don't why they call Z supercompressibility factor. So what do you all think  ?

Comment: @IssamH Vm=f(p,T)